# maven-antrun-plugin: scriptdef ignores CDATA when I add an element

Tags: maven, ant, maven-3, maven-antrun-plugin

I'm using maven 3.5.0 and trying to run a simple javascript code (processing a fileset) with maven-antrun-plugin. In a build.xml of his own it works, and when called from maven-antrun-plugin it works too. If, however, I want to put the whole build.xml in the configuration of maven-antrun-plugin, it doesn't work as expected.

Minimal pom.xml (the script doesn't use the fileset here it's just a test case):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-antrun</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>hello</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <scriptdef name="hello" language="javascript" classpathref="maven.plugin.classpath">
                                    <element name="fileset" type="fileset"></element>
<![CDATA[
      java.lang.System.out.println("Hello World!");
]]>
                                </scriptdef>
                                <hello>
                                    <fileset id="stuff" dir="stuff">
                                    </fileset>
                                </hello>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

If I run:

```
mvn antrun:run@hello
```

No "Hello World!" is printed in the standard output, and this is the build-main.xml that i find in target/antrun folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<project name="maven-antrun-" default="main"  >
<target name="main">
  <scriptdef name="hello" language="javascript" classpathref="maven.plugin.classpath">
    <element name="fileset" type="fileset"></element>
  </scriptdef>
  <hello>
    <fileset id="stuff" dir="stuff"></fileset>
  </hello>
</target>
</project>
```

As you can see, the CDATA is stripped. If however I remove the *element* from *scriptdef* and *fileset* from *hello*, the resulting build-main.xml is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<project name="maven-antrun-" default="main"  >
<target name="main">
  <scriptdef name="hello" language="javascript" classpathref="maven.plugin.classpath">java.lang.System.out.println(&quot;Hello World!&quot;);</scriptdef>
  <hello></hello>
</target>
</project>
```

And I get this output:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building test-antrun 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run (hello) @ test-antrun ---
[INFO] Executing tasks

main:
Hello World!
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.641 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-12-13T16:21:51+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/18M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Am I missing something or could this be a bug/missing feature in maven-antrun-plugin?

EDIT: I opened an issue on jira: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MANTRUN-207

Comment: Can you please explain why do you need to use Antrun plugin? If you are handling Javascript you should take a look at frontend-maven-plugin ?

Comment: I wanted to embed a really tiny portion of code, doing a very simple task (listing the content of a folder and outputting a formatted list, to stdout or to a file), in a pom.xml to be used as a parent of other projects that may need to execute that simple task sometimes. frontend-maven-plugin is an interesting suggestion, but it depends on other files in the project, just like using an ant buildfile, and so I would need to copy those in the child projects. I can also create a custom plugin, but I'd avoid the solution as too overkill.

Comment: I have posted a workaround using <script> task on https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MANTRUN-207?focusedCommentId=16610543&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-16610543.

Comment: @AlexanderSamoylov Sadly, the issue you pointed was closed as "Cannot Reproduce". However, as of this writing the error still exists using maven-antrun-plugin 3.0.0.

Comment: Just ran in to this, still an issues with maven-antrun-plugin 3.1.0.